# PropertyInfo.GetValue returns enumeration constant name instead of value

Tags: c#, reflection

i'm building a serialization component that uses reflection to build the serialized data, but i'm getting weird results from enumerated properties:

```
enum eDayFlags
{
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64
}

public eDayFlags DayFlags { get; set; }
```

Now for the real test

```
Obj Test = new Obj();
Test.DayFlags = eDayFlags.Friday;
```

Output of serialization is then:

> DayFlags=Friday

But if i set two flags in my variable:

```
Obj Test = new Obj();
Test.DayFlags = eDayFlags.Friday;
Test.DayFlags |= eDayFlags.Monday;
```

Output of serialization is then:

> DayFlags=34

What i am doing in the serialization component is pretty simple:

```
//Loop each property of the object
foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
{

     //Get the value of the property
     var x = prop.GetValue(obj, null).ToString();

     //Append it to the dictionnary encoded
     if (x == null)
     {
          Properties.Add(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(prop.Name) + "=null");
     }
     else
     {
          Properties.Add(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(prop.Name) + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x.ToString()));
     }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to get the real value of the variable from PropertyInfo.GetValue even if it's an enumeration and there is only one value?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend making it a habit to represent flags using hex or bit shifting rather than decimal.  It's not a big deal for lower numbers, but for consistency I'd do it everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *are* getting the real value out - it's just the conversion to a string which isn't doing what you expect. The value returned by `prop.GetValue` will be the boxed `eDayFlags` value.

Do you want the numeric value from the enum? Cast it to an `int`. You're allowed to unbox an enum value to its underlying type.

Note that your enum - which should probably be called `Days` - ought to have `[Flags]` applied to it, given that it *is* a flags enum.

Comment: If i try to cast the value i got to int, it says i can't cast it as i got the string version, not the enum value.

Comment: @MathieuDumoulin: That will be because you've called `ToString`. Don't do that...

Comment: Thank you it all works now, thats what happens when you copy paste parts of code on the web cause you don't know how to get something done, you don't see the .ToString() at the end and end up asking questions on SO :(

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behavior.

You did not set the `Flags` attribute on your enum, so `.ToString()` returns the string representation of the enum casted as its underlying type (`int` per default).

Adding `[Flags]` will force your `.ToString()` to return your expected value, i.e. `"Monday, Friday"`

---

If you decompile the `Enum` class, you'll see code that looks like the following in the `ToString()` implementation:

```
//// If [Flags] is NOT present
if (!eT.IsDefined(typeof (FlagsAttribute), false))
//// Then returns the name associated with the value, OR the string rep. of the value
//// if the value has no associated name (which is your actual case)
    return Enum.GetName((Type) eT, value) ?? value.ToString();
else
//// [Flags] defined, so return the list of set flags with
//// a ", " between
    return Enum.InternalFlagsFormat(eT, value);
```

Comment: Oh sorry, i just noticed i was using TOString, wonderful world of copy/paste

Comment: Thanks for the [Flags] attribute, i've marked the other guy as right because he was the first to answer and both of your answers are fine, thanks for your time